# Is there a way to see what numbers I entered after calling an automated service?

Tags: ios, phone.app

On my iPhone 6 is there a way to see what numbers I entered after recently calling an automated service (like when you call the cable or power company and have to press the number that corresponds with the options you provided, like "press 2 to speak with a person, press 3 to pay your bill")? Not the actual number that I initially dialed to make the call but the numbers that I entered after the making the call that I had to press to navigate the options of the automated call service?

Comment: IIRC, those numbers are viewable on the screen while the call is active, but are not saved once the call has been terminated. Logically, these numbers are not technically part of the original phone number, so they are not saved.

Comment: Best solution may be to take a screenshot before terminating the call.

Answer (score 1):

No, this information is not stored anywhere for calls you have made, only vice versa where you write the numbers specifically into a contact with pauses added in the first place for iOS to enter the numbers for you.